# Changing Index Page According to Login

Tags: php, html, session, button, authentication

Im creating an website where i am checking for login and redirecting the user to the index page, if his login was successful i want him to see something else instead of the login button

i have followed this approach for my query

```
<?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION['uid']))
            {
            ?>
            <a href="Login.php"><span class="Login">Login</span></a>
            <?php
            }
            else if(isset($_SESSION['uid']))
            {
            ?>
            <a href="postThread.php"><span>Post</span></a>
            <?php
            }
?>
```

it doesn't seem to work quite the way i want. The 'Login' span is always visible, it would seem that the $_SESSION['uid'] is not being set, but that is not the case. To be honest i don't even know if this is the correct way of doing this

Comment: where do u set session `uid` ?

Comment: session uid was set in my accesscontrol php which redirected me to the page where this belongs

Comment: did u start session in this both pages ?

Comment: session starts only on the accesscontrol so no

Comment: you need to start it on both pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `session_start();` in each page that need to access the session data before accessing (or creating) any session data.

See: [Session Manuel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $linkPage = 'login.php';
    $linkName = 'Login';
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
        $linkPage = 'postThread.php';
        $linkName = 'Post';
    }
 ?>
<a href="<?php echo $linkPage; ?>"><span class="link"><?php echo $linkName; ?></span></a>
```